# How to Make a Ellipse SKPhysicsBody Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, ellipse

I created an ellipse `SKShapeNode` and, I want that shape to have a physical body but, I can't find a `SKPhysicsBody` initializer for an ellipse.

This is the code for the ellipse Shape

```
attackCircle = SKShapeNode(ellipseOfSize: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 400))
```

Sorry in advance if I didn't ask the question properly. This is the first question I am asking online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `CGPath` to set it as an ellipse.  There is a constructor for iOS 7+ which allows you to call:

```
attackCircle = SKShapeNode(ellipseOfSize: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 400))
attackCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(-500, -200, 1000, 400), nil))
```

You set the path of the `attackCircle.physicsBody` using the `polygonFromPath` init.  The `nil` is just to say it's not relative to anything else.

Comment: When I used `attackCircle.physicsBody!.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(-500, -200, 1000, 400), nil)` a error message popped up saying that "SKPhysicsBody does not have a member named path". So I tried your other suggestion and put this in `attackCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake( -500, -200, 1000, 400), nil))` and it worked.

Comment: Okay, it appears that my Swift got messed up, the `SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: <CGPath>)` will work on iOS 7 according to Apple's online documentation.  My Swift was telling me everything was iOS 8+.  I'll edit my answer to reflect this.